# VBA Repeatd summing up of hours until certain criterion

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have a table with 6 columns. [ID, Status, Start Time, End Time, Hours, Sum UP]

[image: Table Example]

I have counted a total amount hours between Start Time and End Time.
Now I have to count a Sum Up of this hours.
The problem is, that the sum up must be counted in a special range, starting from status "Shipped" until status "Checked" appears for only the first time. Then repeat starting again with "Shipped" until "Checked" for the next ID.

```
Sub SUMUP()
   Dim LastRow As Long
   LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   For i = 2 To LastRow
      Cells(i, 6).Value = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("A2:A" & LastRow), Range("A" & i), Range("E2:E" & LastRow))

  Next

End Sub
```

I have this code to sum up a total amount of hours. How can I write a VBA code for my case?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: so ID ending with 098, you want to sum E2:E6? And ID 569: E10:E12?

Comment: @Andreas hi Andreas, no, for ID ending with 098 i want to sum up range E2:E5, and for ID 569 E10:E11. That means excluding hours in status "Checked".

Comment: What about 200 where there are two 'checked' rows?

Comment: "until first checked row" @TomSharpe

Comment: @TomSharpe yeah. That's the problem. Status "Checked" can be repeated. But for me as result only important a sum up betweet "Shipped" and only first status "Checked". Second is not important.

Comment: Do you need the sum to be on every row or is it OK if the sum is only on the last of the rows. For example 098 will have the sum on F5 and F2:F4 is blank?

Comment: @Andreas on the last of the rows is also ok. I need only an automated result, cause a have 100000 rows in a table.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. The other thing is that because the times follow on from each other, checked start time - shipped start time should give the same answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Sub SUMUP()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If Range("B" & i).Value = "Shipped" Then
            For j = i To LastRow
                If Range("B" & j).Value <> "Checked" Then
                    Sum = Sum + Range("E" & j).Value
                Else
                    Range("F" & j).Value = Sum
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j
            i = j
            Sum = 0
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use this formula, if the order Status is sorted in the correct order:

```
=SUMIF(INDIRECT("A"&MATCH(A2,A:A,0)&":A"&ROW(A2)),A2,INDIRECT("E"&MATCH(A2,A:A,0)&":E"&ROW(A2)))
```

This would be an vba solution

```
Sub SUMUP()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim hours As Integer
    Dim ID As Integer
    Dim checked As Boolean

    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    ID = Cells(2, 1).Value
    For i = 2 To LastRow
         If ID = Cells(i, 1).Value Then
             If Cells(i, 2).Value <> "checked" And checked = False Then
                 hours = Cells(i, 6).Value + hours
                 Cells(i, 10).Value = hours
             ElseIf Cells(i, 2).Value = "checked" And checked = False Then
                 checked = True
                 hours = Cells(i, 6).Value + hours
                 Cells(i, 10).Value = hours
             End If
         Else

             ID = Cells(i, 1).Value
             checked = False
             hours = 0
         End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I believe the question is VBA, not formula

Comment: Thank you for advice. I'll try it.

Comment: @Andreas you're right. But i will try to apply this formula to vba code. Maybe this works.

Answer (score 0):

or an array

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(("f"&MIN(IF((($A$1:$A$10="ID")*($B$1:$B$10="shipped")),ROW($A$1:$A$10)))&":"&"f"&MIN(IF((($A$1:$A$10=1)*($B$1:$B$10="checked")),ROW($A$1:$A$10))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, I believe this non-array formula should work:-

```
=IF(AND(B2="checked",COUNTIFS(A$1:A2,A2,B$1:B2,"checked")=1),C2-INDEX(C$2:C$10,MATCH(A2&"shipped",INDEX(A$2:A$12&B$2:B$12,0),0)),"")
```

It just subtracts shipped datetime from first checked datetime.

Multiply by 24 to get the time in hours.